# Verb Form I've Never Seen Before

Tags: grammar

I was doing some reading this morning and came across the following:

> 去年の八月、日本テレビの番組の中で、やはり肝硬変で苦しんでいる九州の高木兼重さんが、「仲間は六人**死んじょる**。七番目はこのわしじゃ」と言った言葉が気味悪く浮かんできた。

I initially thought it might be some kind of -おる form of 死んじる, but I can't find any reference to 死んじる, so I'm wondering if it's some kind of dialectal difference?

I've found one reference to -じょる which refers to a Kagoshima variation of the -て form.

I'm assuming that is probably the answer, but can anyone confirm please?

Answer (score 1):

Dialect. The ちょる・じょる form is common in Yamaguchi prefecture, too. I think it comes from て・で＋おる.

Comment: By the way, Yamaguchi dialect uses 死ぬる instead of 死ぬ, so I don't think the form 死んじょる would be possible.